# extract colon from xml

Tags: php, xml

I have some xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?pageview_candidate?>
<SearchResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/testpad" Version="2.2">
<mms:Image xmlns:mms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/testpad">
<mms:Total>2350000</mms:Total>
```

How can I extract the `mms:Total` value of `2270000` from this using PHP?  I have given the xml the `$xml` variable.

Comment: Those colons indicate namespaces, so mms is a namespace within this XML. What library are you using to parse the XML?

Comment: And is this the whole of your XML? because there's no declaration of the namespaces via an xmlns attribute in your quoted XML

Comment: This isn't valid XML.  `<SearchResponse>`, `<mms:Image>`, and `<mms:Results>` aren't closed.

Comment: Yes, this is just part of it up to the part I need...I just need to take out the total value...I have: $xml->mms:Image and that did not work...I just need the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a useful [blog article here](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302) explaining how to access namespaced elements and attributes using simpleXML, that should provide you with a good starting point.

Comment: Perfect article! Thanks I have saved it.