# Get XML values using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file. Here is a small version of that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="fr">
<title>Liste des ebooks</title>
<updated>2012-03-01T01:23:24Z</updated>
<author>
<name>Drown Del</name>
</author>
<opensearch:totalResults>2338</opensearch:totalResults>
<opensearch:itemsPerPage>100</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
<entry>
<category term="Romans" label="Romans"/>
<category term="Aventures" label="Aventures"/>
</entry>
</feed>
```

First I would like to know how do we call something like `opensearch:totalResults` in XML terms.

And I need your help with obtaining following values with PHP.

`<opensearch:totalResults>2338</opensearch:totalResults>` I need to get 2338 to a PHP variable.

Thank you.

---

Thank you all for your answers.

I could fix it with following way.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmltext);
$val = $xml->xpath('opensearch:totalResults');
echo $val[0];
```

Comment: I honestly cannot believe that you could not find the answer to that via the search function. Virtually each and every DOM example shows how to use `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: I tried with `simplexml_load_string()` and not with `DOMDocument()`. Anyway I could fix my issue. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+colon+php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract colon from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839623/extract-colon-from-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, `opensearch:totalResults` is the *qualified name* of a start tag. It is called a qualified name (you might come across this as QName) because it contains the *namespace* (`opensearch`) for the tag.

For your second question, you can easily [parse your XML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) into a [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and then query it for the value of the relevant tag. There are lots of examples on SO and of course on Google; a basic one from PHP.net is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

**Important note:** Your current XML document does not contain an [XML namespace declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration) for the `opensearch` namespace, and will not parse as a result. You need to add such a declaration by making a modification:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="fr"
      xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
```

If you need more powerful querying you can also use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). A minimal example would look like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//opensearch:totalResults');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could fix it with XPath and I posted my answer here as well.

Answer (score 3):

parse all of this information into PHP using DOM. Ex.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);  //$xml is your xml string
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName("totalResults")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could fix it with XPath and I posted my answer here as well.

Answer (score 1):

**opensearch** is a namespace, so you can try to access it like:

```
$yourXml->children('openSearch', true)->totalResults
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could fix it with XPath and I posted my answer here as well.

Comment: Glad to know you got it on your own

Answer (score 1):

**Check this out the exact result in PHP**

```
<?php
$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="fr">
<title>Liste des ebooks</title>
<updated>2012-03-01T01:23:24Z</updated>
<author>
<name>Drown Del</name>
</author>
<opensearch:totalResults>2338</opensearch:totalResults>
<opensearch:itemsPerPage>100</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
<entry>
<category term="Romans" label="Romans"/>
<category term="Aventures" label="Aventures"/>
</entry>
</feed>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xmlD = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
echo $xmlD->totalResults;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could fix it with XPath and I posted my answer here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Read your xml file with [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) as an object

Then get your variable like this:

```
$object->{'opensearch:totalResults'};
```